# How do I open headless Chrome on aws elastic beanstalk server

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, puppeteer, headless

Hey guys I need a way to open up chrome on the server. Run a webpage with video content on it. run several functions and then close chrome. I tried to do this with puppeteer however I could not get the setExecuteablePath to work and chromium is not an option as it does not support mp4 playback. It is absolutely vital that the video can play as I am capturing screenshots of a canvas that has the video playing in the background. I then compile a WebM file and send it to FFmpeg. All this works great client-side but we are trying to make it faster and have a more consistent environment by running the browser server-side. The server is running Nodejs and runs via AWS elastic beanstalk on a Linux environment.

Here's my current puppeteer code but as I said it fails to run the executeable

```
router.get("/puppeteer", async (req, res, next) => {
  const chromePath = path.join(__dirname, "../chrome/chrome.exe");
  try {
    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

    console.log("chromePath", chromePath);
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
      headless: false,
      defaultViewport: null,
      executablePath: chromePath
    });
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/render/25";
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  res.send(chromePath);
});
```